# SQL query is creating an empty list

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

```
try:
    conn = sql.connect(file)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    print("Connected to Database.")
except:
    print ("Connection failed.")

try:  
    sql_query = "SELECT * FROM strains WHERE Shelf = (?) and 'Strain Type' = (?)"
    args = (shelfplacement, straintype,)
    cursor.execute(sql_query,args) 
    simstrains = cursor.fetchall()
    print("Similar Strains:")
    for row in simstrains:
        print("Strain Type: ", row[0])
        print("Percentage Mix: ", row[1])
        print("Strain: ", row[3])
        print("Shelf: ", row[4])
        print("THC Percent: ", row[9])
        print("\n")
        
    cursor.close()
    
except sql.Error as error:
    print(error)
    
finally:
    if conn:
        conn.close()
        print('The SQL connection is closed')
         
getstraininfo()
```

This code is not filling the `simstrains` variable with a populated list. Is my query statement incorrect? I would appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: You have single-quotes around 'Strain Type' which makes it a string. When you compare anything else to that string, the resulting condition is False thereby returning an empty resultset.

Comment: @mechanical_meat The question is tagged `sqlite`. Why don't you know what DB they're using?

Comment: @Barmar: ah, my mistake didn't see the tag. Thanks.

Comment: This is basically the same question you asked earlier. I told you to use backticks then, why didn't you try it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68385240/this-code-keeps-giving-a-syntax-error-from-the-sql-query-line-from-strain-type

Comment: I used them on the code and it removed the syntax error (thank you). The error I have now is that it is not displaying the results. I used fetchall to create the list simstrains, but the list is empty so the for loop prints nothing.

Comment: Search strain name to find similar strains: 
Lemon G
Connected to Database.
Similar Strains:
The SQL connection is closed  ( this is the result I get from running the code)

Answer (score 0):

try replacing 'Strain Type' with [Strain Type]. columns names with space need to be surrounded by [] or " "